# Connect to Google IoT without the JWT token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, mqtt, google-cloud-iot

I am working on an embedded device which is already able to communicate via MQTT with AWS and Azure for several years.
Now our customers want to be able to use MQTT with Google IoT Cloud as well.
I thought it would be nothing complicated, but I found that I have to generate a JWT token every 24 hours, which is quite heavy for an embedded device (especially a low power one) to handle, to generate a token via the RS256 algorithm, it takes 10 seconds, and with ES256 it takes 6 seconds, with an 80 MHz ARM Cortex-M4.

So I'm looking for a way to avoid having to generate this JWT token, I found in the documentation that Google supports MQTT gateways, but that means we have to keep a gateway server somewhere in the network, which is not very competitive considering what offer AWS and Azure.

Is there a way to avoid having to generate a JWT token (without having to manage an MQTT gateway)?

Or is there someone who offers an MQTT-Gateway service (also for a fee)?

Why did Google decide to use this JWT token as authentication? Wouldn't it have been easier to do as AWS and Azure did?

Answer (score 3):

No, as per the current implementation, [JWT tokens](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts) and MQTT gateway using the [Association only](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways/authentication#authenticating_over_the_mqtt_bridge) authentication method are the only ways to authenticate to Cloud IoT Core.